# Is there a way to rename files based on date modified using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to add an incremental number in front of my existing file names. However, I want to rename them based on their date modified information versus their name.

I’ve managed to add the numbers to the files:

```
[ref]$i = 1;gci -file|Rename-Item -NewName {‘0:D} - {1}’ -f $i.Value++,$_}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a bit more code, in order to be able to sort the items based on their LastWriteTime property and also to have leading zeroes in the numbering based on the number of files in the path.

```
# get an array of sortef FileInfo objects
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File) | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
$i = 1
$max = ($files.Count).ToString().Length
$files | ForEach-Object { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ("{0:D$max}-{1}" -f $i++, $_.Name) }
```